# Axios timeout not working as expected on limited hotspot

Tags: android, ios, react-native, axios

I am using axios for one of my react native project. Here's my config and executing code:

```
const config = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    timeout: 30000
};
var response = await instance.get(route, config);
```

Here is my testing scenario. I have two phones, A and B. From phone A I open my wifi and also create a hotspot. From phone B I connect to that hotspot. Now I turn of wifi on phone A which has hotspot on. For phone B network is available but it shows as limited.

Now if I place an HTTP using above axios configuration, it never times out after 30 seconds for Android devices. But for iOS devices it works as expected. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It happened with me and i solved it manually by doing the following

```
   let source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    setTimeout(() => {
      source.cancel();
      // Timeout Logic
    }, 30000);
   const config = {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       Accept: 'application/json',
   },
   timeout: 30000,
   //Add this
   cancelToken: source.token,

 };
```

Comment: Please note that since Axios v0.22.0 CancelToken has been deprecated. https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into with Hassan's solution is that even though the request did get cancelled, I was using the same token to cancel all requests, so afterwards every request was immediately cancelled, without even attempting. This broke my app.

I solved this using a request interceptor:

```
const myInstance = axios.create(config);

const myTimeoutLimit = 15000;

const guaranteeTimeout = (config) => {
    config.cancelToken = new axios.CancelToken((cancelRequest) => {
        setTimeout(() => cancelRequest('Optional message'), 
        myTimeoutLimit);
    });
    return config;
};

myInstance.interceptors.request.use(guaranteeTimeout);
```

So you basically create a new token per request, if the request takes more than your defined limit, we cancel that particular request.

[Axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation)